# How can i write check constraint

Tags: mysql, regex, constraints, regexp-like

How can I write check constraint for one column say `class_id` where check condition should be: string started with `CLS` and followed by any 5 digit number.
for e.g: `CL100987`, `CLS45678`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do you really mean CL100987 is a valid "_string started with "CLS"and followed by any 5 digit number_" value?

Comment: RDBMS domain integrity constraint

Comment: yes anything afterwards CL or CLS

Comment: Different databases have different string functions etc. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i didnt understand your question i just wanted a simple check condition for above problem no matter which dbms i am using.

Comment: For example how to find "5 digit number" will be different depending on the dbms used.

Comment: @SakshiRay: please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...? String functions differ between databases (as do check constraints capabilities), so there is no answer to your question that would work  "no matter which dbms" you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > try using regex
>
> something like that

> WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_CONDITION,'^CLS.*([0-9]{5})');

> | REGEXP_LIKE -> like specific to regex     | column_condition ->
> explicit    | '^***.*" -> start with and followed by any char    |
> ([0-9]) - > only numerics    | {5} -> the number of numerics in the
> expression
>
> ```
> pay attention to your dbms, some differences 
>
> hope this could help
> ```

Comment: But it also [allows](https://regex101.com/r/EqQHo3/1) `CLS   <some text> 12345<some more text>`. And it does not accept `CL100987`, which was in the question. But it really hard for `CL100987` to be the "*string started with "CLS"and followed by any 5 digit number*"